# Spring MVC & Maven Integration

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm trying to build a Spring MVC project and am having some troubles trying to resolve the follow error.

> HTTP Status 500 - Circular view path [login]: would dispatch back to
>   the current handler URL [/login] again. Check your ViewResolver setup!
>   (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified view, due to default
>   view name generation.)

I entered the following commands via Terminal:

> mvn clean package
>   java -jar target/sprint2-0.1.0.jar

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.teamvirus.src</groupId>
    <artifactId>sprint2</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>0.5.0.M6</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--><dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring3</artifactId>
        </dependency>-->

    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <start-class>com.teamvirus.src.Application</start-class>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestone</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestone</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

LoginController.java

```
package com.teamvirus.src;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

@Controller
public class LoginController {
    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public String login() {
        return "login";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/authenticate")
    public String authenticate(
            @RequestParam(value = "username", required = true) String username,
            @RequestParam(value = "password", required = true) String password) {
        if ((username.equals("admin") && password.equals("admin")))
            return "redirect:dashboard?username=" + username;
        else if ((username.equals("student1") && password.equals("student1"))) {
            return "redirect:dashboard?username=" + username;
        }
        return "wrongpassword";
    }
}
```

Appreciate any assistance rendered.

Edit:

Application.java

```
package com.teamvirus.src;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Post some configuration.

Comment: Hi M. Deinum, I am not sure what you mean by configuration. Appreciate if you could kindly clarify.

Comment: I assume you have a `@Configuration` class/classes somewhre. Post them.

Comment: The only configuration I can see in my project is Application.java. I've edited my post above to include it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are entirely relying on Spring Boot to configure everything, although this shouldn't be a problem for your current view it is.

By default Spring boot registers an `InternalResourceViewResolver` however without any prefix/suffixes.  (See the [source](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration.java#L113)). Assuming you have your views in `/WEB-INF/views` and they are `jsp` files do the following

1. In `src\main\resources` add an `application.properties` file
2. Add a property `spring.view.prefix` with the value `/WEB-INF/views/`
3. Add a property `spring.view.suffix` with the value `.jsp'

Repackage and start your application.

If you don't have this additional configuration `/login` will lead back to `/login` which will lead back to `/login` which will lead back to `/login` which will... Well you get the picture I guess. (`login` is the name of the view you are referring to from your `@Controller`).

Comment: Thanks. I've followed your advice and `application.properties` file with the following:

`@Value("${spring.view.prefix:}")
private String prefix = "/WEB-INF/views/";

@Value("${spring.view.suffix:}")
private String prefix = ".jsp";`

Repackaged, and restarted my application but still get the same error as earlier. Am I doing this correctly?

Comment: Why did you add that to the properties file? That is java not plain properties. You should have something like `spring.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/views/` not the stuff you added.

Comment: My apologies, I'm still learning. That appears to solve the Circular View Path error message. However, none of my JSP files are showing even after cleaning, packaging and running.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20199609/spring-boot-not-finding-jsp-pages-in-war-file. You also might want to check the sample application. To get some more insight in what is happening enable debug/trace logging and see what happens when your pages get resolved.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I appreciate it. I will read and look into this. I've marked your post as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a view resolver? 
Try to add

```
<bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

so when you return `"login"` it will search and load the jsp inside `/WEB-INF/pages/` with name `login.jsp`. Without view resolver it will call your controller method again.

Comment: I've the following in servlet-context.xml. My pages are in 'views'. <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
  <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
 </beans:bean>

Comment: Your `servlet-context.xml` isn't going to be read, so basically all the configuration in there is ignored. Move it to either java configuration or see what is already provided for you by Spring Boot and configure accordingly.