# JSP file not rendering in Spring Boot web application

Tags: spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot web application up and running using embedded Tomcat (the default). When it serves up JSP files as part of rendering the view I specified in my controller, the JSPs are not being rendered as such, and instead print out the contents. For example:

**index.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head></head>
    <body>Test</body>
</html>
```

When the view is rendered in the browsers, the contents above are displayed, instead of the expected contents:

```
Test
```

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Make sure that your `pom.xml` specifies the Tomcat JSP dependency as follows:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

It seems that embedded Tomcat treats the JSP rendering as optional.

As mentioned below, this JAR is sometimes necessary as well:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

(I added provided since this JAR should be included by the servlet container.

Comment: You just made my day! This helped me - even though my issue was slightly different - Spring wasn't even **finding** my .jsp files in `/src/main/resources/webapp/WEB-INF/pages`. Thank you so much!

Comment: Had the same issue as Adrei, it kept complaining about circular dependencies until I added the jar.

Comment: This only will not work. Servlet 3.0 expect jsp to be included in META-INF folder. See this sample application https://github.com/kamoor/spring-boot-sample

Comment: @kamoor I have never seen JSPs in the META-INF and I am quite sure the Servlet 3.0 API does not specify that as the location for JSP files; can you reference where in the spec it says that? Every JSP application I have seen has its JSPs in the WEB-INF. Since you are using 3.0 and Spring Boot, you should consider using Java Configuration instead of XML!

Comment: @NickSpacek I was seeing many SOF questions and servlet 3.0 spec, none of them specifically says what needs to happen for JSPs inside jar. See section 10.10 in http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-oth-JSpec/servlet-3_0-final-spec.pdf it talks only about resources but I see JSP also works that way. My sample app is in https://github.com/kamoor/spring-boot-sample. Have you got above location (webapp/WEB-INF/..) working while packaging as jar? Could you move that jar to another folder or machine and try to run it?

Comment: Haha you asked and answered the question exactly the same time. Nice technique for gaining points :) Will try myself :D

Comment: @Storm It's a checkbox option when posting a question (says something like share your knowledge with the community wiki-style). I think you perhaps do not gain points? Not sure. Regardless, seems like a lot of other people have had the same problem!

Comment: +1 for this - worked for me with a barebones Spring Boot application that was just throwing back 404 errors for any pages I accessed. I'm also using a `src/main/resources/application.properties` file to define a couple `spring.view` properties. It's also listed in the POM for the sample JSP application, but I completely overlooked it: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-jsp

Comment: @NickSpacek had a same issue but it didn't work for me. I am using Jboss EAP 6.4.

Comment: @CraigOtis I tried using the sample JSP but it doesn't work for me. If I comment out the `<scope>provided</scope>` for `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` it will start up, but i get a 404 Not Found for `/` path.

Comment: why this path `webapp/WEB-INF/pages` not exist in my spring boot application I ony have `/src/main/resources` :(

Answer (score 24):

You will need not one but two dependencies (jasper and jstl) in your `pom.xml` for this to work.

```
   <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: @sezil Karil Could you help me on my issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61359718/simple-spring-boot-jar-doesnt-work-except-build-target-folder

Answer (score 16):

For me worked the same like Dan mentioned. Removing the **provided** scope.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
  <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Thanks guy's!

Comment: seems quite helpful, actually ;)

Answer (score 12):

Worked for me too but, I had to remove

```
<scope>provided</scope>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
  <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 10):

Better you can use gradle (which is catching up over Maven). Use this dependency in build.gradle file.

> //Required dependency for JSP

```
providedRuntime 'org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper'
```

Answer (score 9):

1. Make sure, `spring-boot-starter-tomcat`, `tomcat-embed-jasper` and `jstl` dependencies are in the pom.xml.
2. Make sure the packaging type is `war`.
3. If there are multiple modules (IntelliJ), go into Run -> Edit configuration -> Configuration, and select or put `$MODULE_WORKING_DIR$` in the 'Working directory'.

That's it.

Answer (score 7):

I think you missed some configuration because it is easy to integrate JSP just follow below steps

1 - tomcat-embad-jasper dependency

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

2 - Add below configuration is application.properties

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix: /
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp
```

That's it still have some doubt then check it out below link

[Spring Boot and JSP Integration](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r3iy9XHwGQA)

Answer (score 5):

The reason is because you are using the annotation @RestController instead of @Controller

When you annotate a class with RestController, all methods annotated with @RequestMapping assume @ResponseBody semantics by default. In other words, your method #index is serializing the String /webapp/WEB-INF/index.jsp as JSON, instead of mapping its value to a view.

Like mentioned in one of the answers, it has to be

@Controller
public class YourController {
  ...
}

Answer (score 3):

I resolved my issue when in addition to described before:

```
<dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
       <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

`added ViewResolver:`

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableWebMvc
public class SpringServletConfig {
    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver resolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver vr = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        vr.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsps/");
        vr.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return vr;
    }
}
```

from: [Why does Spring MVC respond with a 404 and report "No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [...] in DispatcherServlet"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41577234/why-does-spring-mvc-respond-with-a-404-and-report-no-mapping-found-for-http-req/42785538)

Comment: where i have to add reolver method ??  i think it should be in a class that extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport , am i right ?

Comment: Yes.
Or in a class with the same meaning annotations:
Configuration and 
EnableWebMvc
I have updated example in my answer for this case.

Answer (score 3):

You need jsp compiler jar (tomcat-jasper) in class-path. Embedded tomcat does not come with it.
Remove tomcat-embed-jasper.jar if added already and add below

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: this answer is specifically correct for spring version 2.5.0. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just change the dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

to

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>

    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

Full gradle setup for Spring-Boot with Spring-MVC and with embedded Tomcat server:

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.5.8.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}


apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'


//WEB-MVC
compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.5.8.RELEASE'
compile 'org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper:9.0.1'
compile 'javax.servlet:jstl:1.2'
```

App.class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public final class App {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(App.class)
                .build(args)
                .run();
    }
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
         final InternalResourceViewResolver r = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
         r.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
         r.setSuffix(".jsp");
         return r;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

As seen Spring and Spring Boot has been changing, here is an up-to-date solution.

`build.gradle`:

```groovy
dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: '2.3.0.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.apache.tomcat.embed', name: 'tomcat-embed-jasper', version: '9.0.35'
}
```

`IndexController.java` looks as follows:

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {

    @RequestMapping("/index")
    public String index(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("name", "jancsi");
        return "index";
    }
}
```

`WebConfig.java`:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        registry.jsp("/WEB-INF/views/", ".jsp");
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }
}
```

Here, instead of using `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`, you should use `WebMvcConfigurer` interface, and do not to forget to enalbe the default servlet hander.

And then the structure of folders of jsp files.

```text
src/main/webapp
└── WEB-INF
    └── views
        └── index.jsp
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes tomcat-embed-jasper not available so need to remove provided from the maven dependency of tomcat-embed-jasper.

eg.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
   <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
   <!--scope>provided</scope-->
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use 1.5.8.RELEASE or similar, then, runable example and its explanation is in here https://www.surasint.com/spring-boot-jsp/

You just need this in pom.xml

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    
        org.springframework.boot
        spring-boot-starter-parent
        1.5.8.RELEASE

```
<groupId>com.surasint.example</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-02</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- JSP -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- jstl for jsp -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

And this in application.properties

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp
```

Then you keep your jsp in the /WEB-INF/jsp/ folder.

This is the controller.

```
package com.surasint.example.web.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Map;

@Controller
public class TestController {

    @GetMapping("/testjsp")
    public String list(Map<String, Object> model) {
        model.put("this_time",new Date().toString());
        return "testjsp-view";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and finally resolved it!

My problem was that I had been putting JSP code in my `/WEB-INF/index.jsp` page. However, this page is served directly, without being processed by any servlet or controller. Therefore, it had no chance of being compiled.

[image]

**My solution:**

1. Move `index.jsp` into a subfolder called `views`.

   [image]
2. Edit `web.xml` so that it passes control of the root directory to the dispatcher servlet.

   ```
   <!-- WEB-INF/web.xml -->

   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd" version="4.0">
     <display-name>18-655_lab_1</display-name>

       <servlet>
           <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
           <servlet-class>
               org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
           </servlet-class>
           <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
       </servlet>
       <servlet-mapping>
           <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
           <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
       </servlet-mapping>

   </web-app>
   ```
3. Edit `dispatcher-servlet.xml` to ensure that it's looking in the `views` directory for files ending in `.jsp`.

   ```
   <!-- WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml -->

   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

       <mvc:annotation-driven />
       <context:component-scan
           base-package="com.app.controller" />
       <mvc:default-servlet-handler />

       <bean
           class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
           <property name="prefix">
               <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
           </property>

           <property name="suffix">
               <value>.jsp</value>
           </property>
       </bean>

   </beans>
   ```
4. Using the same `base-package` path as specified in `dispatcher-servlet.xml`, create controller that will return a ModelAndView.

   [image]

   ```
   package com.app.controller;

   @Controller
   @RequestMapping(value = "/")
   public class RootController {

       @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
       public ModelAndView homeGet() {

           return new ModelAndView("index", "message", "IT WORKS!!!");
       }

   }
   ```
5. The syntax `new ModelAndView("index", "message", "IT WORKS!!!")` means that

   - `dispatcher-servlet` looks for a file called `"/WEB-INF/views/" + "index" + ".jsp"`.
   - It compiles the jsp file, replacing all instances of `${message}` with `IT WORKS!!!`.

Therefore, the final thing to do is to put `${message}` somewhere in our `index.jsp` file.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>${message}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

6. Load the project into your Tomcat server, start it, and go to `http://localhost:8080/[project name]/`.

   [image]

Answer (score 1):

For me with Spring Boot version 1.5.10.RELEASE, it worked on adding below maven dependencies.

***Note:*** worked only on not providing the `<scope>` for these two.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
</dependency>
```

And providing below configuration in **application.properties** file

`spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/
 spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp`

Answer (score 0):

I faced the issue like printed the jsp file name in the browser instead of its contents.

By adding the below snippet for jsp page rendering in pom.xml , it renders properly.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: @Crimean.us - Springboot don't need the explicit configuration like your view resolver. Then what made the difference between spring MVC and boot?

Answer (score 0):

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherSe rvlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

  I took the * off so it was just  from web.xml


<servlet>
  <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherSe rvlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please consider, there are some JSP Limitations. You can not set the `packaging` of your `pom` to `jar`. Read this [JSP Limitations](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-jsp-limitations)