# spring boot jsps not getting rendered

Tags: gradle, spring-boot

My build gradle looks like this

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone" }
        mavenLocal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.0.0.RC5")
    }
}

configurations {
    jasper
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: 'war'

war {
    baseName = 'foo-serving-web-content'
    version =  '0.1.1'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone" }
}

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.0.0.M2")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compile("javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0")
    compile("javax.servlet:jstl:1.1.2")
    testCompile("junit:junit")
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '1.11'
}
```

Now the thing is my jsps are not getting rendered, just plain XMLs.
I found this post someone had issues but they are using maven.

[JSP file not rendering in Spring Boot web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20602010/jsp-file-not-rendering-in-spring-boot-web-application)

is there something wrong with my build.gradle ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few things appear wrong:

1. you don't need "spring-webmvc" as an explicit dependency, and you are using a very old version. Just leave that out and you'll get 4.0.3.
2. you haven't included Jasper (despite the fact that it looks like you meant to with the "jasper" configuration) - [example here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-jsp/pom.xml#L26) (it's maven but you'll get the picture).
3. You haven't marked the tomcat dependencies as "providedRuntime" ([see here for example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-static/build.gradle#L49), so I assume you don't need a deployable WAR.

You probably ought to address all of those points, but you can probably get something to work if you do a subset.

Comment: my build.gradle looks like this now 

http://pastie.org/8982991

Now getting 

"HTTP Status 500 - The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application"

Comment: We don't support servlet 3.1 I think, and your jstl looks old. Try those dependencies without the explicit version and let the Boot plugin resolve them for you.