# spring-boot application displaying html code for view when executed in the browser

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am recently start to work with spring-boot in my spring projects, and right now I am facing this problem:

I have one spring-boot application with this main class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

and this controller:

```
@Controller
public class AcessoController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/signin")
    public String signin(Model model) {
        return "acesso/signin";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/admin")
    public String admin(Model model) {
        return "private/admin";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/index")
    public String index(Model model) {
        return "public/index";
    }

}
```

when I run the application and try access the url mapping /signin, for example, the browser display the html code for this view, instead of the actual content.

What I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to render a view using a template engine, or just return a static HTML file?

If you are trying to render a template, then you most likely do not have the right dependency in place to pull in a template engine. (Per your code, I believe this is what you are trying to do.) Even if you don't intend to use the template engine for templates, you will want one to render the HTML for you.  Depending on your spring-boot setup, try starting with **spring-boot-starter-web,** or pull in **Thymeleaf** (*spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf*) or **Freemarker** (*spring-boot-starter-freemarker*) specifically.

If you want to simply return static content and do not want do custom configuration, you'll need to place the files in a certain location and do not need specific controller request mappings.

- http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content

Comment: the view is rendered using only jsp/jstl and they are placed in the directory WEB-INF/jsp from my project. I already have the dependencies spring-boot-starter-web and jstl in my pom.xml.

Comment: Ok, now I see the link. Ley me try this.

Comment: If you are using JSPs, then you will need to pull in "tomcat-embed-jasper". See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20602010/jsp-file-not-rendering-in-spring-boot-web-application

Comment: There's a Spring Boot sample that illustrates the use of JSPs in a Spring Boot app: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/v1.1.8.RELEASE/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-jsp