# Spring Boot, Java Config - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/...] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-java-config

This has been a quite common problem here in stackOverflow, but none of the topics of the same problem solves mine.

We have a template configuration that uses xml config, but now we're trying to move away from that and start using Java config.

So I have a new project using Java config and Spring Boot. We're also using JSP and Tiles 3.

Problem is: it fails to render our admin login page.

Here is the code:

Main config class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
@Import(OnAdminBeans.class)
public class AppConfig extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AppConfig.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(AppConfig.class);
    }
}
```

The `AppConfig.class` is is the main package. Through the `@ComponentScan` that `@SpringBootApplication` brings, it scans the other configurations that are on `mainpackage.config`, so it imports the view config class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class ViewConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/adm/static/**").addResourceLocations("/adm/static/");
    }

//  @Override
//  public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
//      registry.addViewController("/adm/login").setViewName("login-template-tiles");
//  }

    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        registry.viewResolver(viewResolver());
        registry.viewResolver(jspViewResolver());
        registry.viewResolver(tilesViewResolver());
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        CookieLocaleResolver localeResolver = new CookieLocaleResolver();
        localeResolver.setCookieName("locale");
        localeResolver.setCookieMaxAge(30);
        localeResolver.setDefaultLocale(new Locale("pt", "BR"));
        return localeResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public MultipleViewResolver viewResolver() {
        Map<String, ViewResolver> viewsResolvers = new HashMap<String, ViewResolver>();
        viewsResolvers.put(MultipleViewResolver.ViewType.JSP.getKey(), jspViewResolver());
        viewsResolvers.put(MultipleViewResolver.ViewType.TILES.getKey(), tilesViewResolver());

        MultipleViewResolver viewResolver = new MultipleViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewsResolvers(viewsResolvers);
        viewResolver.setOrder(1);
        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver jspViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setOrder(2);
        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public UrlBasedViewResolver tilesViewResolver() {
        UrlBasedViewResolver viewResolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(TilesView.class);
        viewResolver.setOrder(3);
        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public TilesConfigurer tilesConfigurer() {
        TilesConfigurer configurer = new TilesConfigurer();
        configurer.setDefinitions("/WEB-INF/tile-defs/tiles-definitions.xml");
        return configurer;
    }
}
```

The `LoginController.class` is defined as:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/adm")
public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login")
    public ModelAndView login() {
        return new ModelAndView("login-template-tiles");
    }
}
```

And in `tiles-definitions.xml` I have the following definition for login-template-tiles:

```
<definition name="login-template-tiles" template="/WEB-INF/jsp/adm/templates/login-template.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="admin-title" value="Admin" />
        <put-attribute name="content" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/adm/templates/sections/login/index.jsp" />
    </definition>
```

Note that both files exist.

Given all that the *LoginController.login()* **does get called** when i try to access */adm/login*. But it fails to find the proper jsp file, aparently.

It returns a **404**. With TRACE enabled, I get the following log:

```
DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/WEB-INF/jsp/adm/templates/login-template.jsp]

Testing handler map [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping@2118c09a] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'

Looking up handler method for path /WEB-INF/jsp/adm/templates/login-template.jsp

Did not find handler method for [/WEB-INF/jsp/adm/templates/login-template.jsp]

Testing handler map [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping@2c148974] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'

No handler mapping found for [/WEB-INF/jsp/adm/templates/login-template.jsp]

Testing handler map [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping@784c3547] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'

No handler mapping found for [/WEB-INF/jsp/adm/templates/login-template.jsp]

Testing handler map [org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport$EmptyHandlerMapping@533e0604] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'

Testing handler map [org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport$EmptyHandlerMapping@cfd1b4e] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'

No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/WEB-INF/jsp/adm/templates/login-template.jsp] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
```

Any suggestions are appreciated!

**EDIT:**
Ok. By debugging, I found out that it has something to do with the embedded Tomcat. Other than that, I have no clue what is going on.

**EDIT 2:**

Found that the problem is in **org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet#getHandler**. It simply doesn't find a HandlerMapping for that request. Do I have to register one?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

OK! Found the problem.

This link helped me: https://samerabdelkafi.wordpress.com/2014/08/03/spring-mvc-full-java-based-config/

More specifically this configuration:

```
@Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }
```

By setting a default handler, I would no longer get a white page but instead the JSP code as html, which clearly tells me that the JSP was being found but not rendered.

So the answer was on this page: [JSP file not rendering in Spring Boot web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20602010/jsp-file-not-rendering-in-spring-boot-web-application)

I was missing the **tomcat-embed-jasper** artifact.

Comment: this helped me to proceed :)

Answer (score 7):

Add  below dependency to your pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I was facing the same issue, added tomcat-embed-jasper to pom.xml but it was redirecting default error page. I tried adding bean InteralResourceViewResolver and it worked.

Answer (score 4):

The tips here helped me when I got stuck with a similar problem. I fixed it after adding this fragment on my configuration

```
@Override
public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.enable();
}
```