# JSP rendering HTML in Spring-MVC

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

This question has ben asked before but he just said, he solved it and it was a silly mistake on his behave. Which did not help very much. This is what is being rendered in my browser:

[image]

Here is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>SpringMVCpractice</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- ========================================================== -->
    <!-- JSP Configuration -->
    <!-- ========================================================== -->

    <jsp-config>
        <jsp-property-group>
            <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
            <include-prelude>/WEB-INF/jsps/</include-prelude>
            <include-coda>/WEB-INF/jsps/</include-coda>
        </jsp-property-group>
    </jsp-config>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file></welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

index.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Welcome</title>
</head>
<body>
Hello World...
</body>
</html>
```

I am using intellij but I also checked it with Eclipse too and got the same result. I also checked it will multiple browsers.

***************************NOTE*********************
I added:

```
<jsp-config>
        <jsp-property-group>
            <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
            <include-prelude>/WEB-INF/jsps/</include-prelude>
            <include-coda>/WEB-INF/jsps/</include-coda>
        </jsp-property-group>
    </jsp-config>
```

after some reading and still am getting the result. Even if it is not there the same thing happens.

-------------------update-----------------

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven></mvc:annotation-driven>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.practice.comtroller"></context:component-scan>

    <mvc:default-servlet-handler />

    <bean id="jspViewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsps/"></property>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

-----------------upate 2------------------

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {

    @RequestMapping({"/","index"})
    public String index(Model model){
        return "index";
    }

}
```

Comment: How do you deploy and run your application?

Comment: Show us your dispatcherServlet.xml

Comment: I think that your Tomcat doesn't know how to render jsp, add jstl jar in classpath, more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20602010/jsp-file-not-rendering-in-spring-boot-web-application

Comment: @RaphaelAmoedo please see update 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. First: Remove the `jsp-config` and the main problem: You're mapping to `/*`instead of `/` . Just doing this change, everything it will works. So your web.xml will look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<display-name>SpringMVCpractice</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
      <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
      <init-param>
          <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
          <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Comment: That I find this strange. I thought /* would result in web.xml looking for everything beyond the /. Your solution worked and I thank you.