# Spring-boot application not finding index.html

Tags: angularjs, spring

I am wiring a AngularJS and spring-boot application together by hand for the first time. The issues I am running into is my @RestController is not returning the index page:

```
@RestController
public class IndexController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index(){
        System.out.println("Looking in the index controller.........");
        return "index";
    }

}
```

Directory:

[image]

It keeps rendering the default 404 error page:

[image]

----------------UPDATE 1------------------

I have added a configuration file:

```
@Configuration
public class IndexPageConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver(){

        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/app/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        return resolver;

    }

}
```

RestController

```
@RestController
public class IndexController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index(){
        System.out.println("Looking in the index controller.........");
        return "index";
    }

}
```

main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = { "com.serviceImpl","com.service","com.config" },exclude = { ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.class })
public class SpringCrudApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(SpringCrudApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

The above main class is still returning the default 404 error page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure InternalRosourceViewResolver to let the spring know your jsp location

```
@Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/app/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        return resolver;

    }
```

So Spring will append and append location and suffix to your View returned.

I think it is good idea to keep your views separately in any other folder and configure your folder location according to it.

If you want to continue with your current set up

you should return `"/app/index.html"` from your controller.

Spring boot provides White label error page to hide your stack trace when a Server side error/ exception occurs, this will help us from protecting our code from intruders.
If you want to get rid of white label error.

In your `@SpringBootApplication` specify excludes `ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.class`

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = { "com.ekart.app" }, exclude = { ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.class })
```

If you are not using @SpringBootApplication annotatio, you should supply same same excludes in `@EnableAutoConfiguration` annotation

Comment: @Drew1208 try removing while label error. and also remove `spring security` from your pom.xml because spring boot will autoconfigure spring security

Comment: @Drew1208 don't do both, either return "index" if you place IRVR, otherwise return "/app/index.html"

Comment: @Pranani Kinnera I am not using spring security at the moment.

Comment: GOT IT.... Thank you. I needed to do what you suggested and add scan my rest controller. However it is just rendering "index" not the index.html page what is tied into my angularJS

Comment: @Drew1208 I have edited your question, with what is need to do. please follow that edit

Comment: it is returning the string "index" from the controller, not rendering the index.html page.

Comment: @Drew1208 Also include this, as I have faced the same issue when I was learning spring boot http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20602010/jsp-file-not-rendering-in-spring-boot-web-application

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I have added the dependencies but still coming into the same issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106051/discussion-between-pragnani-kinnera-and-drew1208).

Answer (score 2):

On the other hand, Spring will automatically look for the `index.html` page if you put it directly under `webapp` folder. So you don't need any configuration.

This is just another way to do it.