# JSP file contents are getting printed rather than output

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I've made an application using `Spring Boot http://localhost:8080/vehicleApp, the contents of my JSP file are getting printed rather than the expected output.

Below is the code:

**VehicleApplication.java (main class)**

```
package com.Vehicle.prototype;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class VehicleApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(VehicleApplication.class, args);
        System.out.println("Vehicle Application started");

    }

}
```

**MvcConfig.java**

```
package com.vehicle.prototype.config;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver getViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }



}
```

**VehicleController.java**

```
package com.vehicle.prototype.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class VehicleController {

    @RequestMapping(value="vehicleApp")
    public String home(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("greetings", "hello");
        return "vehicleApp";
    }

}
```

**src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/vehicleApp.jsp**
*(These same contents are getting printed as it is)*

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>${greetings}</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

Please let me know what am I missing?

**Thank You**

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20602010/jsp-file-not-rendering-in-spring-boot-web-application

Comment: @reiley Also suggest adding <%@ page isELIgnored="false"%> to the jsp file so that expression language is resolved

Comment: @AlexeySoshin thanks. However add `isELIgnored=false` is creating problem as then `greetings` value is not getting printed