# Simple spring-boot jar doesn't work except build/target folder

Tags: spring-boot, maven, spring-mvc, java-8, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I have a simple spring-boot application but it doesn't work except run from target/build folder.

Here are all my config and files. Please help me to find out why it is not working and what is the wrong I am doing.

It works perfectly fine while I run  from target folder `java -jar target\demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT` and by running from IDE(Eclipse).

and my weburl is `http://localhost:8082/demo/edit.html`. I just copied this jar to different machine/folder it is not longer working.

```
package com.example.demo;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
public class DemoApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

```
package com.example.demo;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
@Controller
public class DemoContoller {
    @RequestMapping("/edit.html")
    public ModelAndView edit(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("edit");
        return model;
    }

}
```

```
package com.example.demo;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewResolverRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan
public class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        registry.viewResolver(resolver);
    }
}
```

**application.yaml**

```
spring:
  mvc:
    view:
      prefix: /WEB-INF/view/
      suffix: .jsp
  output:
    ansi:
      enabled: ALWAYS
server:
    servlet:
      contextPath: /demo
    port : 8082
    error:
      whitelabel:
        enabled: false
```

```
**edit.jsp**
<% request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"); %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
helllloooooo Demo
</body>
</html>
```

```
**pom.xml**
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
        <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-collections4 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- jstl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
             <version>8.0.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
             <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>true</executable>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I just run `mvn clean package spring-boot:repackage` to build the project.

Here is my project/folder structure:

[image]

Maven build :

```
$  mvn clean  package spring-boot:repackage
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] --------------------------< com.example:demo >--------------------------
[INFO] Building demo 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ demo ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Users\User\Downloads\demo\target
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ demo ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ demo ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 3 source files to C:\Users\User\Downloads\demo\target\classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ demo ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\User\Downloads\demo\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ demo ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ demo ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ demo ---
[INFO] Building jar: C:\Users\User\Downloads\demo\target\demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO]
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.2.6.RELEASE:repackage (default-cli) @ demo ---
[INFO] Replacing main artifact with repackaged archive
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  3.201 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-04-22T15:52:06+08:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Updated pom.xml after comments** 
Still it is not working

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-collections4 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- jstl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
             <version>8.0.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**Update**
removed from application.yaml , so i see this error page now.

```
    error:
      whitelabel:
        enabled: false
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by _it's not working_? can you provide the log or possible error? try building the jar file using `mvn clean package -DskipTests`

Comment: @HMD i tried this also ```mvn clean package -DskipTests``` it just create a jar file of 5KB and throws this error while running : no main manifest attribute, in target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar. I mean not working , ```http://localhost:8082/demo/edit.html``` doesnt work/load even the jar file run without any error. Which works perfectly if running/started from IDE(Eclipse)

Comment: use `spring-boot-parent` instead of `dependency management` and remove options specified on `spring-boot-plugin`. then run the `mvn clean package -DskipTests`. it's not a solution, but if it works, then you have the clue to search more

Comment: You are mixing different spring boot version use only one version 2.2.6.RELEASE and rebuild your project...

Comment: @HMD @khmarbaise i have tried using ```spring-boot-parent``` , removed options ```spring-boot-plugin```. used only single version of springboot. It didnt help. check i have added updated pom.xml but it is not helping

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue with my spring boot mvc application. The application was working fine when I run using "mvn spring-boot:run" or "java -jar target/myapplication.jar" (Notice target/). It never worked when I tried to run with "java -jar myapplication.jar" for below scenarios,

- by placing the jar at a different location (without target/ directory)
- by running the jar from inside /target directory (cd target/ and "java -jar myapplication.jar")

The control/request reaches the server and get processed but failed to redirect to view (404 - NOT FOUND).

As a workaround, I changed packaging from jar to war in the pom.xml and it started working (as per my requirements).

`<packaging>war</packaging>`

One can explode the jar/war and can find the packing is different for jar and war.

Hope this helps. Happy coding!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

edit.html could be the problematic part. Can you remove .html and leave just "/edit" and then try "http://localhost:8082/demo/edit". If that works we will understand that it's due to the file extension over there.

Comment: My request mapping is @RequestMapping("/edit.html"), how it will work with /edit ?

Comment: change requestmapping to /edit and try to test it with /edit. if it works then this is because of "." in the url and we can find a solution