# getResourceAsStream returns null when I run Spring Boot project within IDE but not when I run the jar built by Maven

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea

in the following line

```
    InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/static/index.html");
```

inputStream is `null` when I run the Spring Boot project within Intellji. what is the problem? and how can I see the exact command that Intellji use when I hit the run button?

update:

this the commanad Intellji use to run:

```
/usr/java/jdk-11.0.1/bin/java -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -noverify -Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dspring.jmx.enabled=true -Dspring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain -Dspring.application.admin.enabled=true -javaagent:/opt/JetBrains/idea-IU-201.7223.91/lib/idea_rt.jar=36753:/opt/JetBrains/idea-IU-201.7223.91/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /home/mehrdad/ocr/main/ocr-web/target/classes:/home/mehrdad/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.6/commons-io-2.6.jar:....
```

as you see the classes directory is in class path, and the static directory is inside it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61359718/simple-spring-boot-jar-doesnt-work-except-build-target-folder maybe its will help you.

Comment: Why do you expect it to work?

Comment: Do you have /static folder in your intellij directory structure? Or is it something that is built when compiling and generating a jar? It might exists under your classes/static inside your jar, but not in your src/resources/static

Comment: of course I have.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen becuase it is a standard Maven project, and the `src/main/resources/static` is in classpath, it is copied to `target/classess/static`

Comment: @user3618000 And the file is there at runtime?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen yes