# Spring MVC Java based config - JSP not resolving

Tags: java, spring, maven, jsp, spring-mvc

I am developing a little demo project with *Spring MVC* on a Tomcat with *hibernate* and *JSPs*. The application was working with *thymeleaf* as a view resolver but I need to rewrite my *thymeleaf* template as a .JSP. So I needed to reconfig everything. I am also trying to only use annotation configuration files without any xml.

The problem is that I am seeing the source code of my JSP-File without resolving.

The Request-Mapping and the program logic already worked with **thymeleaf + spring**. I am getting no error messages in the log files. I tried a lot of changes so my config files may be inconsistent at the moment. Any pointers or advice is appreciated.

My config files are below:

**MyWebAppInitializer:**

```
public class MyWebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    private static final String CONFIG_LOCATION = "MvcConfiguration";
    private static final String MAPPING_URL = "/";@Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        WebApplicationContext context = getContext();
        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(context));
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("DispatcherServlet", new DispatcherServlet(context));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping(MAPPING_URL);
    }
    private AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext getContext() {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        context.setConfigLocation(CONFIG_LOCATION);
        return context;
    }
}
```

**MvcConfiguration:**

```
 class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {

        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }
}
```

**BenutzerController:**

```
@Controller
 public class BenutzerController {

    @Autowired
    BenutzerRepository repository;

    @ModelAttribute("Benutzer")
    public Benutzer loadEmptyModelBean() {
        return new Benutzer();
    }

    @ModelAttribute("userList")
    public List < Benutzer > userList() {
        return toList(repository.findAll());
    }

    @RequestMapping("/verwaltung")
    public String verwaltung(@RequestParam(value = "message", required = false, defaultValue = "Defaultvalue") String message, ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("message", message);

        return "verwaltung";
    }
```

**pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>


    <name>benutzerverwaltung</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

**EDIT: SOLUTION**

editing the pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.29</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using Spring Boot's embedded Tomcat? According to the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20199609/spring-boot-not-finding-jsp-pages-in-war-file), you may need to add a dependency: `compile("org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper")`. However, I've never got JSPs to work properly with an embedded tomcat -  you can create a war file instead, as it says in [the docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-jsp-limitations).

Comment: Thanks. After adding a maven dependency like this it worked: